# My Bootstrap Carousel is not advancing, nor running automatically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a Bootstrap Carousel that is not working and I have searched other Bootstrap carousel threads and can't seem to find an answer. Usually the answer to most of the questions on here is that the jQuery library either isn't linked correctly, or isn't linked at all and I *think* mine is.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<nav class ="navbar navbar-default" role = "navigation">
    <div class= "container">
        <div class = "navbar-header">
            <a class = "navbar-brand" href="#featured"> <span class="subhead">Wisdom Pet Medicine</span></a>
        </div>
        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#featured">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#mission">Mission</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#staff">Staff</a></li>
            <li><a href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
        </ul>     
    </div> 
</nav> <!--main nav-->

<div class= "carousel slide" data-ride= "carousel" id = "featured">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active"><img src= "img/carousel-lifestyle.jpg" alt="lifestyle"></img></div>
        <div class="item"><img src= "img/carousel-exoticanimals.jpg" alt="animals"></img></div>
        <div class="item"><img src= "img/carousel-fish.jpg" alt="fish"></img></div>
        <div class="item"><img src= "img/carousel-mission.jpg" alt="mission"></img></div>
        <div class="item"><img src= "img/carousel-stateoftheart.jpg" alt="motto"></img></div>
        <div class="item"><img src= "img/carousel-vaccinations.jpg" alt="vaccine"></img></div>
    </div> <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <a class ="left carousel-control" href= "#featured" role = "button" data-slide ="prev"><span class= "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
    <a class ="right carousel-control" href= "#featured" role = "button" data-slide ="next"><span class= "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div> 
</div><!-- carousel-->
</div>
    </header>
    <script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have some CSS as well, it may not be related, but i'll include it anyways:

```
body {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight:200;

}
.navbar {
    border-radius: none;
}

.navbar-nav {
    padding-right: 20px; 
}

.navbar-header>a {
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-weight:150;
    color: black !important;
}


.navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    color: green !important;

}

.carousel {
    position:relative;
    top:-20px;
}
```

Comment: If you open the dev tools, does the console give any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a different version of jQuery (you're using `v1.8.3`) starting at a minimum of version v1.9.1.

I would suggest checking out one of these if using a CDN.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

or

[CDNjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/)

Comment: This solved it! Thanks so much! This was driving me nuts!

Comment: No problem and glad I could help!